# handling server response AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the process of working on a simple project (or at least I thought to be simple) Where a user clicks a button, and a random saying generated from php appears in the above textbox. I do not have access to the php file so I can't see the code and feel a bit lost. The problem I'm having I believe, is an error in the way Im handling the response from the server (the handleServerResponse function). Any advice would be appreciated.

In an attempt to debug, I've seen this message: (I've changed the url)

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:somephp.php. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

the code thus far:

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
var xmlHttp;

if(window.ActiveXObject){
    try{
       xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }catch(e){
       xmlHttp = false;
       }
    }else{
    try{
       xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch(e){
       xmlHttp = false;
    }
  }

if(!xmlHttp)
    alert("Error 1");
  else
    return xmlHttp;
}


$("#BtnReset").click(function () {
    $("#TBSaying").val("");
})

$("#BtnGetSaying").click(function () {
    process();
})


function process(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://somephp.php", true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    }else{
       setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }
}

function handleServerResponse(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
       if(xmlHttp.status==200){
        xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
        xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
        message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data
        $("#TBSaying").val(message);
       }else{
         alert('error 2');
         }
    }
}
```

Read through the JQuery documentation and started fresh, uploaded it to the same server in which the php resides and it works. here is the final code: Thanks to all that advised!

```
$("#BtnReset").click(function () {
    $("#TBSaying").val("");
})

$("#BtnGetSaying").click(function () {
    process();
})


function process(){
            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.get("http://somephp.php",function(data){
             $("#TBSaying").val(data);
  });
 }
```

Comment: Please describe more specifics about what you want help with.  What exactly do you observe (e.g. what happens when you run this code)?  What exactly to you expect to happen?  Have you seen any errors in the debug log?  Have you placed `console.log()` statements in  your server response function to see exactly what data is returning there?  Basic debugging steps are expected before you post here so you can describe what steps you've already taken and where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: Your question, as it stands now, is not something we can answer (insufficient information).  Much more information from you is required.  Without that additional information, this question will need to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript seems horrible, but alas, wrong
   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is a server-sided (php?) bug, sorry.

tell the server guys to add something like

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

to see if your javascript is correct ^^

on a sidenote,

1. alert("Error 1"); should probably use console.log or throw new Error() instead..
2. why have xmlHttp as a global, can just use process(e){ var xhr=e.target;...} instead
3. don't do this setTimeout('process()', 1000);  , do setTimeout(process, 1000);

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I selected this as the correct answer because your comment "your javascript seems horrible" made me go back and do it the more correct, cleaner (though maybe not perfect) way. I've updated my original post above. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax calls from a browser are restricted by what is called "same origin restrictions".  Basically this means that, by default, you can only make an Ajax call back to the same server that the web page came from.  That means you cannot make a regular Ajax call to a server on another domain, port or protocol.

You can read about the same origin policy [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

There are a three ways around this restriction, but all require cooperation from a server.

1. **CORS.**  The server you are making the request from puts headers in its responses that tell the browser whether a cross origin request is allowed or even what domains it is allowed from.  This gives the browser permission to complete Ajax calls that are not from the same origin.
2. **JSONP.**  You can read more about [JSONP here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).  Basically, you request a script from the target server and the script is coded in such a way that it will provide you the answer you want (usually in the JSON data format).
3. **Server proxy.**  You find or code a server proxy that will request the data from the other server for you.  Because server to server communication is not limited by the same origin restrictions, you can sometimes find another server that allows cross-origin requests to it that will then get the data for you and then return it to you.

Comment: how about using [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) as a safer alternative to situations where simple ajax requests can't be made to server because of origin restrictions?

Comment: Actually it is called the "same-origin policy" - and it isn't just the domain, also the protocol, port and host must be the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So as long as all of the js code is correct, if I upload this project (html and js) to the same server where the php resides, then it should work?

Comment: @exeleon - if your PHP file is on the same server as the host web page you're trying to do the ajax call from, then you will pass the same origin policy because you will be contacting the same origin.  I can't speak to whether you will or won't run into other problems.